# How do I capture the Worklight defaultOptions:onFailure event?

Tags: authentication, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters

I have a Worklight 6.1.0.1 hybrid app that I'm running on iOS.  The app uses adapter-based authentication. The app prepares the invocation data makes the following call when the Login button is clicked:

```
singleStepAuthRealmChallengeHandler.submitAdapterAuthentication(invocationData, {});
```

If the WL service is down, or if the mobile device has no network access, the invocation will timeout. I see the following in the Xcode console:

```
defaultOptions:onFailure Request timed out for http://myipaddress:10080/myapp/apps/services/../../invoke. Make sure the host address is available to the application (especially relevant for Android and iPhone apps).
```

How can I capture this timeout event, so that I can update the UI with a proper message?

Answer (score 0):

*Update May 23rd based on comments:*

What is your exact flow?

You should first use `WL.Client.connect({onSuccess: ..., onFailure:...});`
If connection to the server is successful, you will enter the challenge handler. Otherwise, you will enter onFailure and there you can create the custom error handling.

---

*Previous answer attempt:*
The below is when trying to `connect()` to the Worklight Server.

If you want custom handling for when the client fails connecting to the server I believe you need to enable and use the option `onConnectionFailure` in initOptions.js:

```
var wlInitOptions = 
// # The callback function to invoke in case application fails to connect to Worklight Server
    //onConnectionFailure: function (){},

}
```

Otherwise, Worklight's default dialog will be displayed.

Comment: In my app, Worklight's default dialog is never displayed.  I only know about the timeout because I see it in the log.

Comment: @richardsun, make sure you verify do a WL.Client.connect before you invoke your adapter. connect has options: onSuccess, onFailure. If success, invoke the adapter procedure. If failure for whatever reason, display your custom error.